# Can I use a monitor's MST DisplayPort-Out port to output duplicated video?

Tags: video, display, displayport, mst

I have a U2414H Dell monitor, and it sadly doesn't have an HDMI out port, but it does have a DisplayPort out port intended for multi-stream transport. As I'm looking to livestream from my PS4 via OBS on a computer, without an expensive capture card, could I use the MST port to mirror the video signal of the monitor to a computer for OBS streaming?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No.

> Multi-Stream Transport allows multiple displays to be connected to a single DP port on a desktop PC or laptop. It does this by combining multiple video signals into a single stream (a process known as multiplexing) and sending it over a DisplayPort cable to a device that unbundles the signal.

[Source](https://www.tripplite.com/products/multi-stream-transport-mst-hub-technology)

You can't get the video signal out of that port, it is not intended for that.

What you'll need is a HDMI Splitter between your PS4 and the monitor, and then a HDMI grabber to bring the signal on the PC. There are also combined devices intended for streaming.